# Splitting field in finite field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

> What is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^8}-1$ over $\mathbf F_p$?

I'm confused, is not $X^{p^8}-1=(X-1)^{p^8}$ then the splitting field is $\mathbf F_p$?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, does $F_p$ contain all roots of $X^{p^s}-1$?

Comment: Yes, because the only root is 1,  no?

Comment: So, is it the splitting field?

Comment: Yes; my question is because is a problem of Algebra S.Lang; Thank you.